# Postman and Chrome different API responses

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postman, odata

I have been making the exact same API request one from postman and one from a react app which is located in localhost so on my machine but when I evaluate the response I get different results between the two.

The request contains odata commands and looks like this:

```
Articles?$expand=Category&$select=Category
```

The authorization is over a bearer token which I already checked and is correct in both request and the headers and URL are the exact same too.

The only thing different is the response where chrome is missing a few entries inside an array which is supposed to contain these Category fields which are JavaScript objects.

The response body looks like this:

```
{
    "@odata.context": ... , value: [
        {
            Category: ...
        }
    ]
}
```

What is missing is some of the category objects that are there in postman so basically postman is working as intended.

Also for some reason the request appears two times in the network tab one time as OPTIONS and one time as GET which I don't know why either. Somebody good a clue what the culprit could be in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Postman and a browser are different things. Clearly, the service you're querying is differentiating the requests and returning slightly different results based on the source of the request. The details of the requests (headers, etc.) are probably slightly different.

> Also for some reason the request appears two times in the network tab one time as OPTIONS and one time as GET which i dont know why either. Somebody good a clue what the culprit could be in this situation?

That's because you're making the request from a web browser, and so the Same Origin Policy comes into effect. The browser sends a "preflight" request via OPTIONS to the server, which apparently returns appropriate CORS headers to allow the main request, and so then sends the main GET request. See:

- [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)
- [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/)

Comment: So it is likely the problem is with the server then i see.

Comment: @OhLongJohnson - That depends. You'll want to examine the full details of the requests being made to be sure. Perhaps there's some header Postman is sending but Chrome isn't, or vice-versa, which the server uses to differentiate.

Comment: Already tried to copy the request from the dev tools into postman via curl command tho and it was still different, as in the same as the one i did manually in postman.

Comment: I have a similar situation. I tried copying and pasting the header in which the browser sends a cookie  into postman, and this makes the response the same as the browser . Without it I seemed to be getting an old, cached response

Answer (score 0):

For  me the issue was a difference between the **request.body** sent to the API from Postman and the request.body sent from my frontend app. **The one sent from my app had a missing field.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35165699)